# Is it possible to define object type with dynamic set of keys

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a function that accepts an array of string as an argument and builds an object that has each of the array item as a key. Like this:

```
function buildObject(keys: string[]) {
  let obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = i;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Is it possible to define a return type for this function so that attempt to access object key that is not defined would result in compiler error?

```
const obj = buildObject(['a', 'b', 'b']);
console.log(obj.a) // OK
console.log(obj.d) // I want a compiler error here
```

Comment: Imagine you pass not static variable, but decoded string from back-end server. How compiler can know what you pass in advance?

Comment: @Justinas I'm not saying it's possible. I just want either a confirmation that it's not or an idea on how to do this.

Comment: It's not compile time issue, it's runtime issue, so compiler can not detect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the keys array as readonly and then use the type of its values as keys for the result object.

```
function buildObject<T extends string>(keys: readonly T[]): Record<T, number> {
  let obj = {} as Record<T, number>;
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = i;
  }
  return obj;
}

const obj = buildObject(['a', 'b', 'b']);
console.log(obj.a) // OK
console.log(obj.b) // OK
console.log(obj.d) // Error
```

Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wEY64w

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with TS so I tried to figure it out and I will try to explain. I tried something like this.

My thought process is, you need to make `buildObject` signature infer from your input but you need to tell TS what kind of input you have. Obviously an array of strings.

```
function buildObject<T extends string>(keys: T[]) {}
```

Then, you need to tell what's the return type (your object). Here, you need to use a mapped type so your object has keys that are type of each literal of your array of keys. I also added `?` so your initialization to `{}` works.

```
type Obj<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]?: number;
};
```

Full code:

```
type Obj<T extends string> = {
  [key in T]?: number;
};

function buildObject<T extends string>(keys: T[]) {
  let obj: Obj<T> = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    obj[keys[i]] = i;
  }
  return obj;
}

const obj = buildObject(['a', 'b', 'b']);
console.log(obj.a); // OK
console.log(obj.d); // Compiler error
```